Highlight selected row in DataTable
I have a table that is using the DataTables library that appears in a modal with data. The idea here is that I will click on a row which will load information into a textarea. I have all of that working. What I want to do is have the row that is selected stay highlighted. I have attempted multiple versions of this but I'm still not getting the result that is wanted.
I have a clean fiddle that shows the modal and a stripped down version of the returned table here:  https://jsfiddle.net/yogx3ksf/1/ In this fiddle
I have tried to add in the select JS with this fiddle but still not getting this to work
https://jsfiddle.net/dw1jrohx/
var columns = []; // Initialize columns variable globally

$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#customerTable').DataTable({
        select: {
            style: 'single'
        }
    }); // Initialize DataTables with select

  var secondTable = null; // Initialize secondTable variable

  $('#customerTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var userId = $(this).data('userid');

    console.log("Clicked on row with userId:", userId);


Ensure that you include the DataTables Select plugin since it's necessary for the select functionality.
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>

Here's how your code should look with the integration of the DataTables Select plugin and proper handling of row selection and highlighting:
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#customerTable').DataTable({
    select: {
      style: 'single'
    }
});

$('#customerTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
  } else {
    table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  }
  var userId = $(this).data('userid');
  console.log("Clicked on row with userId:", userId);
 });
});


snippet:



$(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $('#customerTable').DataTable({
                select: {
                    style: 'single'
                }
            });

            $('#customerTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                var userId = $(this).data('userid');
                if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                    $(this).removeClass('selected');
                    $('#infoArea').val('');
                } else {
                    table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                    $('#infoArea').val('Selected User ID: ' + userId);
                }
            });
        });
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="customerTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>User ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-userid="1">
                <td>1</td>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>john.doe@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-userid="2">
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Jane</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>jane.smith@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Additional rows as needed -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <textarea id="infoArea" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>




thanks for your answer. I have double checked to make sure I am including these libraries and I have event made sure I was using the version of jquery you posted however, the selected row is still not highlighting. I have seen other examples of CSS being included or needed for the selection, I don't have any CSS do I need any? I have no output of errors in the console either.

@weggie no need to add any css. I updated my code and added snippet so you can run it and test the code

Thank you for the snippet. I'll try to integrate it. Appreciate ya, will report back.
